WordPress save function not working on the frontend
I'm creating a custom block (theme) on WordPress Gutenberg and I'm using React, the functionality works on the edit function which is the WP admin area (this makes me believe the code is good) but doesn't work on the front-end(website) and I have no idea that's happening. It is a gallery section where each videos play when you click on it
My code below
  save: ({ attributes }) => {
      const { src, poster, text, thumbVideos} = attributes;
      const blockProps = useBlockProps.save( {
         className: 'pd-block pd-inline media-container',
     } );
      return (
         <section { ...blockProps }>
            <div className="display-con display">
               <div className="full-img" >
                  <video className="displayed-video" controls src={src} poster={poster}></video>
                  <p className="text">{text}</p> 
                  <div className="overlay"></div> 
               </div>
               <div className="thumb-bar-video">
                  {thumbVideos.map((thumbVideo, index) => (
                     <div className="thumb-video-item" key={index}>
                        <video src={thumbVideo.src} poster={thumbVideo.poster} text={thumbVideo.text}></video>
                     </div>
                  ))}
               </div>
            </div>
         </section>
      );
   },

I have tried looking up Gutenberg blocks, but unfortunately I can't put my hands on something

The reason your WordPress Gutenberg block isn't working on the front-end is because WordPress only utilizes React for the backend editor, while the front-end receives plain HTML output, you need to create a separate JavaScript file like front.js to target the elements on the frontend and implement the functionality. Also, ensure the new file is enqueued in your theme or plugin's PHP file to ensure it's loaded properly on the front-end.
